# How to detect nexus 4 through another nexus 4 using bluetooth low enerrgy

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Google sample code for BLE. I have 2 nexus 4 phones. When i install the app on one phone and try to scan for any other BLE enabled devices, it does not display any device. Is there any problem in the code or BLE on phone cannot detect BLE enabled mobile phones?

Comment: Are your devices discoverable?

Comment: Yes my devices are discoverable

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#roles

You have to first understand that how BLE works. There are central and peripheral roles. Read the link above, you will find that now Android only supports central role, and central cannot be discovered by another central.

Comment: So you are saying one Nexus 4 mobile cannot discover another nexus 4 mobile using BLE as both are supportin only central role

Comment: Yes, the current API just doesn't support that.

Comment: The iOS API has support for both roles, so it is very probable that the Android API will also support this before long. But for now there is only peripheral support.